# Jenkins: Disable Jobs based on calendar event

Tags: jenkins

Scenario: I have Job(s) which get triggered by a commit to git or can be triggered manually. 
We have freeze period sometimes, during which these jobs aren't supposed to be run. These freeze times are **random** in nature and they are intimated via meeting requests in email.
So, I manually disable the jobs whenever I receive these meeting requests and enable them after the freeze period.

1. Is there an approach/mechanism for Jenkins/plugins to look at a calendar and if there are blocked events/appointments/meetings, Jenkins/plugins can disable the job(s)?
2. Are there any other ways of addressing this problem?
3. If there are no such plugins and If I have write my own plugin, where do I start?

Comment: Another possibility would be doing it the other way around. Have you calendar application call the Jenkins API and disable the Job. Might not be possible dependending on your calender app, but I thought I suggest it.

Comment: Thanks @AndréStannek, I will try that.

Comment: this is solid question. I am still interested in the answer @AndréStannek 
if you had some progress, would you care to share it here?